# How to create a graphic object in a label

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, io, gdi+

So in my project I need to read a .txt file that consists of "."'s and "#"'s. This .txt file is the map for a labyrinth. The #'s are impassable objects and the .'s are items that should be able to be collected.

I've already managed to parse in the text and create a `TableLayoutPanel` that contains `Label` controls, which contain the # and .'s. However I want to replace the .'s by circles that are centered in the cell.

How do I do this?
Here is what I have.

```
public class Import: TableLayoutPanel
{
    public int zeilen, spalten;
    TableLayoutPanel tlp = new TableLayoutPanel();
    public TableLayoutPanel getData(string path)
    {
        StreamReader sr;
        TableLayoutPanel tlp = new TableLayoutPanel();
        tlp.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        tlp.CellBorderStyle = 0;


        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            try
            {
                using (sr = new StreamReader(path))
                {

                    spalten = Int32.Parse(sr.ReadLine().Trim());
                    zeilen = Int32.Parse(sr.ReadLine().Trim());


                    TableLayoutColumnStyleCollection Columns = tlp.ColumnStyles;
                    TableLayoutRowStyleCollection Rows = tlp.RowStyles;
                    foreach (ColumnStyle Column in Columns)
                        tlp.ColumnStyles.Add((new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100.0F / Convert.ToSingle(spalten))));
                    foreach (RowStyle Row in Rows)
                        tlp.RowStyles.Add((new RowStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100.0F / Convert.ToSingle(zeilen))));


                    for (int i = 1; i <= zeilen; i++)
                    {
                        string line = sr.ReadLine();
                        for (int j = 1; j <= spalten; j++)
                        {
                            Label l = new Label();
                            tlp.Controls.Add(l, j-1, i-1);

                            l.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

                            l.Text = line.Substring(j-1, 1);
                            l.Name = "l" + i.ToString() + "r" + (j).ToString();
                            if (line.Substring(j - 1, 1) == "#")
                                l.ForeColor = Color.Green;

                            if (line.Substring(j - 1, 1) == ".")
                            {
                                l.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
                                Graphics g = l.CreateGraphics();
                                g.DrawEllipse(new Pen(Color.Blue), l.Location.X, l.Location.Y, tlp.Width, tlp.Height);


                            }


                        }
                    }
                    return tlp;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) { MessageBox.Show(e.Message); MessageBox.Show(e.StackTrace); return null; }
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: Anything like this should be done in the Paint event, however I strongly suggest you to use a more graphics 'friendly' environment like WPF instead of WinForms

Comment: Sadly, I need to use winforms in this case(the task says I have to). I tried to use a graphics event but I don't know how I can get the locations of the specific cells of .'s. Do you have an idea how I could make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a `Label` you can create its `Paint` event along with it, inlined as a `Lambda`:

```
Label l = new Label();
l.Name = "Label #" + (i * zeilen).ToString("00") + ":" + j.ToString("00");
l.Text = "ABCE";
l.Paint += (ss, ee) =>
{
    // do your painting here:
    using (LinearGradientBrush lgb =
       new LinearGradientBrush(l.ClientRectangle, Color.Cyan, Color.DarkCyan, 0f))
        ee.Graphics.FillRectangle(lgb, l.ClientRectangle);
    ee.Graphics.DrawString(l.Text, Font, Brushes.Black, 1, 1);

};
```

You can cast the `sender ss` to `Label` and access all its properties. Note the the above `Lambda` will be called whenever the `Label` needs to be painted, that is **whenever you invalidate** it or one of its containers or **whever the system** needs to refresh it.

It will then always use the **current** data, so when you change the text later it will use the new text:

```
Label oneOfMyLabels = tlp.Controls["Label #03:02"] as Label; // pick or find the right one!
if (oneOfMyLabels != null)
{
  oneOfMyLabels.Text = "New Text";
  oneOfMyLabels.Invalidate();  // optional when change the text of a Label
}
```

Note that you always need to **store the data** that control the painting **outside** of the the `Paint` event, either at class level or somehow bound to the control.

When changing the colors for example you would store them somewhere and use those values for creating the gradient brush instead of hard-coding them..

Whenever you change those data you need to call `Invalidate` on the `Label`. The `Text` change will do that for you but **other** data need **you** to trigger re-painting..!

Also note that since you **Labels** are set to `Dock.Fill` the **Cells** they sit in you can draw the circles there as well:

```
 ee.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, 0, 0, l.Width - 1, l.Height - 1);
```

Of course I inserted the `LinearGradientBrush` just for fun..

Answer (score 0):

Use Paint event from your form:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx

You can draw everything there. From rectangle, circle, string, etc....

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    private readonly Pen greenPen = new Pen(Brushes.Green);
    private readonly Pen redPen = new Pen(Brushes.Red);
    private readonly Font testFont = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10f);

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(redPen, 0f, 0f, 100f, 100f);
      e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(greenPen, 10f, 10f, 200f, 200f);
      e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello Graphics", testFont, Brushes.Blue, 30f, 30f);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried using a paint event already, but I don't know how I can get the locations of my "." cells in my paint method.

Comment: It is easier to create your own UserControl and use Paint there, instead of using TableLayoutPanel and Label and then find the ".".